# How to get a particular word from a particular line from the output of unix command in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

I would like to run a command in a shell script for ex `ls -al` and I need to extract the 3rd word of the 5th line.  Can anyone help?

What I currently have is:

```
str = $(ls -al foo | cut -d" " -f3)
```

This is storing all the words in 3rd field, but I am unable to get the word from 5th line.

Can anyone tell me how to get a specific line, or a more optimized solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change your command to:

```
ls -al |head -5|tail -1|cut -d" " -f3
```

Answer (score 3):

try `str=$(ls -al foo | awk 'NR==5{print $3;exit}')`. `ls` command output is not suitable for parsing. Also `cut` counts consecutive spaces as separate fields, so identifying word with `cut` is always risky

Experiments:-

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ ls -al foo
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 abasu synopsys 4096 2013-05-09 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 abasu synopsys 4096 2013-05-09 15:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 abasu synopsys    0 2013-05-09 15:08 a
-rw-r--r--  1 abasu synopsys    0 2013-05-09 15:08 b
-rw-r--r--  1 abasu synopsys 1362 2013-05-09 15:11 c
-rw-r--r--  1 abasu synopsys    0 2013-05-09 15:08 d
-rw-r--r--  1 abasu synopsys    0 2013-05-09 15:08 e
-rw-r--r--  1 abasu synopsys    0 2013-05-09 15:08 f
[[bash_prompt$]]$ ls -al foo | awk 'NR==5{print $3;exit}'
abasu
[[bash_prompt$]]$ ls -al foo | awk 'NR==6{print $5;exit}'
1362
[[bash_prompt$]]$ str=$(ls -al foo | awk 'NR==6{print $5;exit}')  #for 6th line,5th word
[[bash_prompt$]]$ echo $str
1362
```

Comment: is it because i used `ls -al` instead of `ls -al foo` ( now modified)? or is it because I stored the output in `str` and you need to do `echo $str` to see it in output?

Comment: I am printing the string print "$str"